# refactoring and removing 'for' statements when circling over many enum structures

Tags: java, enums, refactoring

My class have an Enum as attribute.
It uses a String to set this attr.
There are many Enum classes.
How can I refactor it?

```
public void setType(String s) {  

for (MyEnum1 e : MyEnum1.values()) {  
    if (e.name().equalsIgnoreCase(s))  
    this.type = e;  
}  
for (MyEnum2 e : MyEnum2.values()) {  
    if (e.name().equalsIgnoreCase(s))  
    this.type = e;  
}  
for ...
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

Use `MyEnum1.valueOf(String)`.

Comment: + `toUpperCase()` to achieve case-insensitivity